# What is the simplest solution to this elementary geometry problem?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

### The Problem

Given a triangle $ABC$, points $M$ and $N$ are chosen in such way that the midpoint of segment $BM$ is coincident with the midpoint of side $AC$, and the midpoint of segment $CN$ is coincident with the midpoint of side $AB$. Prove that points $M$, $N$, $A$ are collinear.

The drawing is provided.
[image: The Drawing]

### The Solution

Below I provide my own solution of the stated problem.

Let $P$ be the midpoint of $AB$, and $Q$ the midpoint of $AC$. We are going to prove that $A\in MN$.

1. $\overline{CP}=\overline{PN}$, $\overline{AP}=\overline{PB}$ (by statement of the problem), $\angle CPB = \angle APN$ (these angles are vertical by definition) $\Rightarrow _\Delta BPC\cong _\Delta APN$ (SAS congruence).
2. $_\Delta BPC\cong _\Delta APN\Rightarrow \angle PCB=\angle PNA\Rightarrow BC\parallel AN$ (from the congruence of alternate angles).
3. $\overline{BQ}=\overline{QM}$, $\overline{AQ}=\overline{QC}$ (by statement of the problem), $\angle BQC = \angle AQM$ (these angles are vertical by definition) $\Rightarrow _\Delta BQC\cong _\Delta MQA$ (SAS congruence).
4. $_\Delta BQC\cong _\Delta MQA\Rightarrow \angle CBQ=\angle AMQ\Rightarrow BC\parallel AM$ (from the congruence of alternate angles).
5. $BC\parallel AN$ and $BC\parallel AM$, so $BC$ is parallel to two line segments with a common endpoint. Clearly, as $ABC$ is a triangle, point $A$ is not on line $BC$. But by [Playfair's axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playfair%27s_axiom), at most one line parallel to the given line can be drawn through the point not on this line. Thus, two segments with a common endpoint can be parallel to the same line if and only if they are on the same line. So we conclude that $\overline{AM}$ and $\overline{AN}$ are collinear, and thus, $A$, $M$, $N$ are collinear, QED.

### The Question

I'm looking for the simplest solution of this problem you can find. By simplest I mean the most elementary, using only basic facts of geometry, preferrably more elementary than the one I came up with above.

Answer (score 8):

$ACBN$ and $ABCM$ are parallelograms, because their diagonals are bisected by the point of intersection. So, $AN \parallel BC$ and $AM \parallel BC$.

Comment: A clever observation indeed, thanks for it! So instead of proving triangle congruency, you just straight out to proving parallelograms, which is nice. Let's see what others would come up with, too!

Answer (score 3):

Let $X$ be the intersection of $BM$ and $AC$, and similarly for $CN$ and $AB$ with $Y$.

Rotate $\triangle BCX$ by $180^{\circ}$ about $X$ (and the same with $\triangle BCY$ about $Y$) to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

As **JMP** does, we'll call $ \ X \ $ the midpoint of $ \ \overline{AC} \ $ and $ \ Y \ $ the midpoint of $ \ \overline{AB} \ \ . \ $  Then $ \ \overline{BX} \ $ and $ \ \overline{CY} \ $ are *medians* of $ \ \Delta ABC \ \ . \ $  These intersect at the *centroid*  $ \ P \ $ of the triangle and thus  $ \ \overline{BP} \ $ and $ \ \overline{CP} \ $ have $ \ \frac23 \ $ of the length of  $ \ \overline{BX} \ $ and $ \ \overline{CY} \ \ , \ $  respectively.  Hence,   $ \ \overline{MP} \ $ and $ \ \overline{NP} \ \   $  have $ \ \frac43 \ $ the length of   $ \ \overline{BX} \ $ and $ \ \overline{CY} \ \ , \ $  respectively, making triangles $ \ \Delta MPN \ $ and $ \ \Delta BPC \ $ similar (the two triangles having vertical angles at $ \ P \ ) \ . $ So $ \ \overline{MN} \ $ and $ \ \overline{BC} \ $ are parallel, as we have pairs of alternate interior angles among the two triangles.

If we call $ \ Q \ $ the midpoint of $ \ \overline{BC} \ \ , \ $ then $ \ \overline{AQ} \ $ is also a median of  $ \ \Delta ABC \ \ . $  The similarity of $ \ \Delta MPN \ $ and $ \ \Delta BPC \ $ places $ \ A \ $ on the line $ \ \overline{MN} \ \ . $

[The proposition is *very* simple to prove analytically:  placing $ \ A \ $ at the origin (and $ \ B \ $ and $ \ C \ $ at arbitrary coordinates) and finding the coordinates of the midpoints $ \ X \ $ and $ \ Y \ \ , \ $ and thence those of $ \ M \ $ and $ \ N \ \ , \ $ it is straightforward to show that the slope of side $ \ \overline{BC} \ $ is the same as the line containing $ \ \overline{MN} \ \ . \ $ It is then found that the equation of said line passes through the origin.]